# HTML Multiple Forms: Fill out information - Click Button for Show Duplicated Empty Form

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very specific issue and I actually have no idea where to start. I am not sure if I am allowed to ask a question like this if I don't really have any code?

I am trying to create an html form where you can enter in a location, name, address, phone number etc. Once you have filled that "location" out you can click a button that says "Add New Location". When you click that it will add another empty form where you enter in your information for the next location and can continuously do this... say you have 40 locations... you could do it 40 times.

Is this even possible with html/css/js? Or would this need to have a database and more intensive development?

Comment: The answer depends on your endgoal. If you don't need to save those and can discard them each time, then yes, it is possible to do with js+html+css. If you want to remember that data, then you need some backend.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Yes, I would need to save each location as they are entered and then send them in an email

Comment: If you only need to send them as email, you don't really need a database. You will pass those values to the server, form an email there and send them right away.
You will only need a database if you need to store them to show somewhere else lately(after you sent an email). 

But server side is not really optional in either of these cases

Comment: So there isn't a simple solution for this ?

Comment: If by simple solution you mean using only front-end(js+html+css) then no.

Comment: okay.. hmm thank you for your responses!